# Proving By reduction from the Halting Problem

Tags: logic, computer-science, computational-complexity

I want to solve the following exercise in Computability and Complexity Theory:

> By providing a reduction from the HALTING problem to REACHABLE-CODE,
>   prove that REACHABLE-CODE is undecidable.

REACHABLE-CODE is defined like this:

> INSTANCE: A source code S, a number n of a line in S.
>   QUESTION: Is there an input I for S such that the run of S on I will reach the code on line n?

I am not sure how to solve this. Can i  Solve this by assuming that ther IS an algorithm for the REACHABLE-CODE problem and use it as a subroutine in an alrogithm that solves the HALTING problem?

Comment: Why do people keep tagging questions about deciability with [decision-theory]?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My guess: because there isn't a "decidability" tag. If you start typing "deci", the only options are "decimal-expansion" and "decision-theory", so for someone who doesn't what decision theory is, the latter seems closer to "theory of decidability". (But I guess you knew this already, and your question wasn't intended to be taken literally.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Obviously my question was meant as a rhetorical rant... ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Why not create a decidability tag, and have redirect it to computational-complexity or whatever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is what it means to reduce one problem to another: you assume you have an algorithm for the reachable code problem, and show that this would allow you to build an algorithm for the halting problem.